# Spring Boot Returning 401 Statused Custom Object From Exception Handler

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, exception, resttemplate

I have an Spring Boot rest API that have an LoginController for doing simple authentication processes. This is the token validation action.

```
@PostMapping("validatetoken")
public ResponseEntity<ValidateTokenResponse> validateToken(
        @RequestBody ValidateTokenRequest validateTokenRequest, HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception {

    if (StringUtils.isEmpty(validateTokenRequest.getToken())) throw new AuthenticationFailedException("token parameter cannot be null or empty");

    Boolean isValid = authenticationService.validateToken(request, validateTokenRequest.getToken());
    ValidateTokenResponse response = new ValidateTokenResponse();
    response.setIsValid(isValid);
    response.setToken(validateTokenRequest.getToken());
    return new ResponseEntity<>(response, isValid? HttpStatus.OK : HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED);
}
```

And in my api I'm catching all errors in a `ResponseEntityExceptionHandler` and converting a custom object this way.

```
@ExceptionHandler(AuthenticationFailedException.class)
@ResponseBody
protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleAuthenticationFailed(AuthenticationFailedException ex) {
    LogManager.error(ex);
    ApiError apiError = new ApiError(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED);
    apiError.setMessage(ex.getMessage());
    return buildResponseEntity(apiError);
}
```

But when I want to call this api using `RestTemplate` like below I'm getting and exception like *java.net.HttpRetryException: cannot retry due to server authentication, in streaming mode*.

```
ResponseEntity<String> responseEntity =
    restTemplate.exchange(
        this.validateTokenUrl,
        HttpMethod.POST,
        requestHttpEntity,
        String.class);
```

But if I change `HttpStatus` from `ExceptionHandler` to except `HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED` I can get true `ApiError` object from the client. What can cause this problem and how can I resolve it?

EDIT: Created a [github repo](https://github.com/yusufduyar/question-sample) that mimics my problemic parts of my project.

Comment: I just tried using "Controller" and "ControllerAdvice" instead of "RestController" and "RestControllerAdvice" annotations. The exception handler started working.

Comment: The exception handler is working with both Controller and RestController and also two types of Advices. My problem is about getting the result of api call from client when api throws AuthenticationException. Client is getting an error on `restTemplate.exchange()` like "_I/O error on POST request for "http://localhost:8080/api/auth/validatetoken": cannot retry due to server authentication, in streaming mode_". So I could not get `ApiError` class instance and details from api response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make it clear, I suggest to autowire resttemplate in separate config file with below detail

```
@Bean
  public RestTemplate restTemplate() {
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    restTemplate.setErrorHandler(new ErrorHandler());

    SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory = new SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory();
    requestFactory.setOutputStreaming(false);

    restTemplate.setRequestFactory(requestFactory);

    return restTemplate;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a default behavor for SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory (uses the JDK's internal http client)

A simple fix is to use apache http components library:

```java
ClientHttpRequestFactory  requestFactory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory();
restTemplate.setRequestFactory(requestFactory);
```

see this link for more details: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/issues/441#issuecomment-92033542

Comment: This worked with no other modification to my code. My error handler was able to get the 401 status and the  body of the error.
/n
`ClientHttpRequestFactory  requestFactory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory();`
`restTemplate.setRequestFactory(requestFactory);`

Answer (score 0):

By default `RestTemplate` uses `DefaultResponseErrorHandler`. This error handler throws exception whenever 4xx/5xx response is send from REST API.

If you want custom error handling, just register your custom error handler via `restTemplate.setErrorHandler`, where you would use your implementation of `ResponseErrorHandler` interface.

Comment: I'm already using an error handler that implements `DefaultResponseErrorHandler`. But it doesn't work. I have pushed related parts of my project to github repo [here](https://github.com/yusufduyar/question-sample).